# Change value of JSONValue

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to change value of JSONValue?

My code:

```
type JSONValue = 
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | { [x: string]: JSONValue }
    | Array<JSONValue>;

interface Data {
    name: string;
    values: JSONValue;
}

const d: Data = {
    name: "John",
    values: {"first": 1, "second": 2}
}
```

I would like to change the "first" value:

`d.values["first"] = 2;`

but this return me error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"first"' can't be used to index type 'JSONValue'.
> Property 'first' does not exist on type 'JSONValue'.

Comment: Consider not calling a type `JSONValue`, since JSON is always a string

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's the *value* of a JSON text, so the name is fine

Comment: Btw, your `JSONType` union is missing `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is complaining about the assignment because it doesn't know that you stored an object in `d.values`. According to your type declaration, it might as well be an array, string, number or boolean, and assigning `.first` to those is not allowed.

If you want to tell TypeScript "but I know it's (currently) an object", you can use a type assertion:

```
(d.values as { [x: string]: JSONValue })["first"] = 2;
```

If you want to tell TypeScript that `data.values` is always an object that may hold arbitrary properties, change the definition of your `Data` interface:

```
interface Data {
    name: string;
    values: { [x: string]: JSONValue };
}
```

If you are not actually certain yourself, check the type first before assigning:

```
if (typeof d.values == 'object' && !Array.isArray(d.values)) {
    d.values["first"] = 2;
}
```